# How do I install module named 'caching3'?

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to run a code, but I keep getting "No module named 'caching3'", I have installed almost every type of module with the phrase 'cache' in it...I am stuck, I keep getting the same ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: Use `pip install caching`. Then try again.

Comment: already tried this, didn't work. I still get the same error.